# Emacs global-abbrev-table with bracketed definition

Tags: emacs, unicode, elisp

See the following `abbrev-table` for emacs:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table '(
    ("8in" "∈")
    ("(x)" "⊗")
    ))

(setq-default abbrev-mode t)
```

If I evaluate the region above and then type in "8in", this string is abbreviated to ∈ in my emacs buffer. Great. However, if I type in "(x)", this is not abbreviated to anything. I was hoping for an abbreviation to  ⊗. What have I got wrong in my `global-abbrev-table` definition? I have also tried with `\(x\)` and `\\(x\\)`, but neither result in an abbreviation of "(x)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(let ((syntab  (copy-syntax-table)))
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\( "w" syntab)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\) "w" syntab)
  (set-syntax-table syntab))
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table '(("(x)" "⊗")))
```

Of course, you might not want `(` and `)` to have word-constituent syntax in general...

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Terrific, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Emacs currently only accepts word syntax for characters composing an abbreviation.

BTW can't see a reason for that.

Comment: Check the documentation.  It does support non-word syntax, just not by default.

Comment: @Stefan That's really good news. However I'm read in define-abbrev: Define an abbrev in TABLE named NAME, to expand to EXPANSION and call HOOK.
NAME must be a string, and should be lower-case.
;;;; Makes 'lower-case' any sense beside of word characters?